# Windows 8 Metro: How to get clicked GridViewItem?

Tags: gridview, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm building a Windows 8 Metro application (C#, XAML) with a GridView, and I'd like to show a popup near the GridViewItem that the user clicked on. I was planning on getting the GridViewItem UIElement through the click event arguments and using its coordinates to determine where to place my popup.

However, I haven't yet found a way to get a reference to the actual GridViewItem UIElement that was clicked! The events that I've tried below seem to expose only the DataContext through their EventArgs, and not the actual UIElement:

```
object sender // is the GridView
ItemClickEventArgs.ClickedItem // is the DataContext of the GridViewItem
ItemClickEventArgs.OriginalSource // is the GridView
SelectionChangedEventArgs.OriginalSource // is null
SelectionChangedEventArgs.AddedItems.First() // is the DataContext of the GridViewItem
```

If it matters, my GridView.ItemSource is a CollectionViewSource, with its Source bound to a collection of viewmodels.

Is it possible to get the clicked GridViewItem through some event I've overlooked? If not, what angle should I look into to work around it? I can at least get the click coordinates relative to the GridView through the PointerPressed event and see what I can do to locate the item that way, but really hoping I don't have to go down that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VisualTreeHelper might help you placing it to either the GridView/GridViewItem and finding it's child/parent that is if you want to find the UIElement. To determine what UIElement was click inside a container should be solve using the **VisualTreeHelper**.

More on VisualTreeHelper is found here [Visual Tree Helper example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21495/Understanding-the-Visual-Tree-and-Logical-Tree-in)

IF you don't want to use VisualTreeHelper, I would create an attach property that all my GridViewItem click will be pass themselves as dependencyObject to the the GridView's attach property (Which is custom and you can get more out of it).

Comment: Thanks, that cracked it. VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates() is the way to go, which returns a collection of UIElements at a given point (from the PointerPressed event) which you can then filter down to the GridViewItem.

Answer (score 6):

I've also implemented this behavior in an app - using a Flyout popup from the Callisto library in conjunction with a clicked GridViewItem.

It is MUCH easier to simply call ContainerFromItem to get the relevant GridViewItem control:

```
private void itemGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var clickedItem = itemGridView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem);

    // Open the flyout now
    Flyout flyOut = new Flyout();
    if (clickedItem is GridViewItem)
        flyOut.PlacementTarget = clickedItem as UIElement;
    else
        flyOut.PlacementTarget = sender as UIElement;

    flyOut.Placement = PlacementMode.Left;
    SolidColorBrush br = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    flyOut.Background = br;
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    tb.Text = "I'm in your flyout messing with your text";

    flyOut.Content = tb;
    flyOut.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Thanks to [this thread here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/a3336abf-6577-48f7-97cd-f0e69ed9416f) for pointing me in the right direction.