# How to get tapped item in gridview

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I want to get the tapped item in my gridview, but I can't use itemclick event with some reason, after get the item, I also want to convert it as an object which the item hold. The gridview had DataTemplate, when I see the e.OriginalSource value in tapped event, it is a TextBlock. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question here:

[Windows 8 Metro: How to get clicked GridViewItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781836/windows-8-metro-how-to-get-clicked-gridviewitem/12229508#12229508)

If you're trying to get the GridViewItem object for the item the user clicked on, this can be captured by the GridView's ItemClick event by using the GridView's ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem method.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Enable IsTapEnabled="True"  and Create Tapped event in Gridview

```
<GridView x:Name="categoryItemsGV"
                                Margin="5,5,0,0"
                                IsItemClickEnabled="True" IsTapEnabled="True" Tapped="categoryItemsGV_Tapped"
                                SelectionMode="Single"
```

Step 2: This GridView bind with **TableModel** list, and below Tapped Event

```
  private void categoryItemsGV_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedTableModel= (TableModel)(sender as GridView).SelectedItem;

        }
```

This **selectedTableModel** contain selected items model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "onItemInvoked" event of control ListView as below code:

```
//item click handler for list view
document.getElementById("yourListViewId").addEventListener("iteminvoked", function(e) {
    e.detail.itemPromise.then(function (invokedItem) {
         WinJS.Navigation.navigate("url to another pages", { objectToTransfer: invokedItem.data });
        });
});
```

Using "invokedItem.data" to pass whole object data which ListViewItem holds

Comment: Hi @vixfive, thanks for your quick reply, I forgot to mention I'm using C#&XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using attached behavior aka [WinRT Behavior](http://winrtbehaviors.codeplex.com/) and use it to relay tapped event to a command in your view model

Answer (score 0):

The `DataContext` of your `TextBlock` is what you want.